# How to unzip a zip file that contains multiple different csv files programmatically

Tags: zip, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I want to extract a zip file which consists of multiple different csv files using Azure data factory or databricks.
Is there any other way which can be used to programmatically extract it?

I tried ADF's zipdeflate option and databricks's unzip command, but both didn't work.
Whereas when I use 7-zip to extract the file manually, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Compression mechanism by default provided by Azure, if it is not working , then you can go for Custom activity in ADF, in there you can use either C# or Python to unzip it and store it wherever you want it.

In ADB, You can install specific package at cluster level and unzip it.

There are multiple solution to this issue, choose whichever option is feasible and cost effective.

Comment: i have used several libraries in python such as zipfile,pyunpack,py7zr.But none of them worked. Most of the time it gives error `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` so i checked with python-magic library as well, and it says `Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`. I also tried all copy options and format in adf, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7180/pyspark-etl-code-excel-xml-json-zip-files-azure-databricks/ ..

Sharing you one link , which does unzip the data using ADB. You may give a try.